# ¿Como evito esta información innecesaria al imprimir un dato de mi dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Al querer mostrar solo una celda de mi archivo de excel, me sale información adicional que no me sirve (como se muestra en la foto), las líneas de código que muestran esa información, están entre esos dos comentarios que dicen Ayudaaaaa. Yo solo quiero que se muestra la palabra camisetas, gracias por su ayuda, un lindo día.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import pandas as pd
excel = pd.ExcelFile('ProyectoAdmOperaciones.xlsx')
dataframe = excel.parse('Productos')
salir = False
while not salir:
    opcion = input("Desea hacer algun pedido? (Si/No): ")
    if (opcion.upper() == "SI"):

        #Ayudaaaaaa
        print("Cuantas unidades desea comprar de ")
        print(dataframe['Productos'][0:1]) 
        unidades = input()
        #Ayudaaaaaa

    elif (opcion.upper() == "NO"):
        salir = True
    else:
        print ("Por favor ingrese una opcion valida")
print ("Gracias por usar nuestro programa")
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás haciendo un rebanado (slicing) de la columna al hace `[0: 1]`, esto retorna un objeto `pandas.Series` en vez del item de la celda, lo que ves no es más que la representación de dicho objeto.

Si quieres obtener solo el item basta con hacer:

```
dataframe['Productos'][0]
```

o:

```
dataframe.loc[0, 'Productos']
```

o mejor aún:

```
dataframe.at[0, 'Productos']
```

Con eso te imprimirá algo como:

> Cuantas unidades desea comprar de
>   Camisetas

Si quieres que se imprima todo seguido puedes usar formateo de cadena, por ejemplo:

```
if (opcion.upper() == "SI"):
    producto = dataframe.at[0, "Productos"]
    unidades = input(f"¿Cuántas unidades desea comprar de {producto}?: ")
```

que mostrará:

> ¿Cuántas unidades desea comprar de Camisetas?:

Comment: Muchas graciaaaaas!!!!!!! :)))